# laravel route to a new page that has information depending on clicked value

Tags: php, laravel, database

So I'm very new to laravel, and I want to know the best way on how to do the following:
So I have on the main page couple of villas with their information such as Title and address (all information is from the table in the database) and the goal is when I click on its name I want it to route me to a view blade that has all its information such as images, address, description(all its values in database), and when I click on the other villa also give its own information.

maybe depending on each unique id?
but with one route?

please some help!

Comment: I recommend reading the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters

Comment: Thank u but I read it, and the whole image on how to do it is still not clear @shaedrich

Comment: Can you share [the code, you already have](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to go from there?

Comment: on clicking the name send the id and then fetch the data and then send it back to a view.

Comment: @kuro Could you elaborate on this by making it an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: yes since you are not providing the code i will put a sample code of my own.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I hope this gives you fair idea and a starting point

In the route file

```
//Your route for the individual villas
Route::get('/villa/{id}', function (id) {
    $myvilla = Villa::find(id);

    return view('villa.profile', ['villa' => $myvilla]);
   
});

Route::get('/villas', function(){
  
   $myvillas = Villa::all();

   return view('user.profile', ['villas' => $myvillas]);

});
```

In the view where all the villas are displayed, do display the ids in the link

```
<ul>
@foreach ($villas  as $villa)
   <li><a href="URL::to('/villa/'.$villa->id)">{{ $villa->name }} </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Note for security reasons use uuid for your ids for this approach.
I exempted the Controller bit so you need to use controllers to add more features as well.

Comment: You could just type-hint `Villa` and don't need to `Vanilla::find(id)` manually

Comment: `function (id)` needs to be `function ($id)`, `Villa::find(id);` needs to be `Villa::find($id);` and `href="URL::to('/villa/'.$villa->id)"` needs to be `href="{{ URL::to('/villa/'.$villa->id) }}"`

Answer (score 0):

web.php:

```php
Route::get('/villas/{villa}', function (Villa $villa) {
    return view('villas.details', compact('villa'));   
})->name('villas-details');

Route::get('/villas', function(){  
   $villas = Villa::all();

   return view('villas.overview', compact('villas'));
})->name('villas-overview');
```

villas.blade.php

```php
<ul>
@foreach ($villas as $villa)
   <li><a href="{{ route('villas-details', compact('villa') }}">{{ $villa->name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap each villas with a href tag as below and send the id.

```
 <a href="{{route('villas.details',$villa->id)}}" >Villa 1</a>
```

i generally use tables so my code is something like this.

```
 @foreach($villas as $villa)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{{route('villas.details',$villa->id)}}" >
              {{$villa->name}}
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
           other column(s)
        </td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

the route for this should be as follows

```
Route::get('details/{id}', [
    'as' => 'villas.details',
    'uses' => 'VillaController@getDetails',
]);


public function getDetails($id)
{

    $villaDetails= Villa::find($id);

    return view('villas.detail-info', compact('villaDetails'));
        
}
```

In the detail-info blade do what ever you like with the villaDetails.

A bit of advice if you are new always use dump and dd to check the data. :)

Comment: You could just type-hint `Villa` in your controller method and don't need to `Vanilla::find($id)` manually

Comment: can you provide sample code i don't get it

Comment: You can take a look at my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73527435/7451109

Comment: More information: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: yeah but i prefer sending id and fetching

Comment: Laravel provides a way to write less code by doing some stuff for you so you don't have to do it on your own. Nonetheless, there's more than one way to skin a cat and that's fine.